# Deploy Prompt (Chat) Flow with Chat UI?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a Chat Flow using Azure Machine Learning Prompt Flows. For testing, it has a very neat chat window, where I can use the chat UI to test my deployment.

However, the only way I can access this Prompt Flow outside of the Azure Machine Learning is via the API. Is there a way to deploy the whole chat window UI from Azure Machine Learning that is used to test the Prompt/Chat Flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can´t, you have to build your chat window UI.